# I couldn't access to this page in

Tags: html, css, asp.net, .net, blazor-webassembly

I need help in debugging my homework.

Context: I am using Blazor Web Assembly Standalone to build this app called `CarRentalManagement`.

I have created the data structure for the Vehicles page. But I can't access the page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUcPJ.png)

The page supposed to be accessible and looked like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjHff.png)

I'm suspecting that it could be my .NET faulty. Do you guys have any idea?

Thanks :)

`Vehicle.cs` (in `Domains` folder of `CarRentalManagement.Shared`):

```
namespace CarRentalManagement.Shared.Domain
{
    public class Vehicle : BaseDomainModel
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string? LicensePlateNumber { get; set; }
        public int MakeId { get; set; }
        public virtual Make? Make { get; set; }
        public int ModelId { get; set; }
        public virtual Model? Model { get; set; }
        public int ColourId { get; set; }
        public virtual Colour? Colour { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Booking>? Bookings { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Index.razor` (in `Vehicles` folder of `CarRentalManagement.Client`):

```
@page "/vehicles/"
@inject HttpClient _client
@inject IJSRuntime js
@attribute [Authorize]

<h3 class="card-title">Car Vehicles</h3>
<br />

@if (Vehicles == null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">Loading Vehicles...</div>
}
else
{
    <table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Make</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>License Plate Number</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var vehicle in Vehicles)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@vehicle.Make.Name</td>
                    <td>@vehicle.Model.Name</td>
                    <td>@vehicle.Year</td>
                    <td>@vehicle.LicensePlateNumber </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/vehicles/view/@vehicle.Id" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <span class="oi oi-book"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="/vehicles/edit/@vehicle.Id" class="btn btn-warning">
                            <span class="oi oi-pencil"></span>
                        </a>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(()=>Delete(vehicle.Id))">
                            <span class="oi oi-delete"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private List<Vehicle>? Vehicles;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Vehicles = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Vehicle>>($"{Endpoints.VehiclesEndpoint}");
    }

    async Task Delete(int vehicleId)
    {
        var vehicle = Vehicles.First(q => q.Id == vehicleId);
        var confirm = await js.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", $"Do you want to delete {vehicle.LicensePlateNumber}?");
        if (confirm)
        {
            await _client.DeleteAsync($"{Endpoints.VehiclesEndpoint}/{vehicleId}");
            await OnInitializedAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

`VehiclesController.cs`:

```
namespace CarRentalManagement.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class VehiclesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public VehiclesController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        // GET: api/Vehicles
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetVehicles()
        {
            if (_unitOfWork.Vehicles == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var vehicles = await _unitOfWork.Vehicles
                                            .GetAll(includes: q => q.Include(x => x.Make).Include(x => x.Model).Include(x => x.Colour));
            return Ok(vehicles);
        }

        // GET: api/Vehicles/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetVehicle(int id)
        {
            if (_unitOfWork.Vehicles == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var vehicle = await _unitOfWork.Vehicles.Get(q => q.Id == id);

            if (vehicle == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(vehicle);
        }

        // PUT: api/Vehicles/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutVehicle(int id, Vehicle vehicle)
        {
            if (id != vehicle.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _unitOfWork.Vehicles.Update(vehicle);

            try
            {
                await _unitOfWork.Save(HttpContext);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!await VehicleExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Vehicles
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Vehicle>> PostVehicle(Vehicle vehicle)
        {
            if (_unitOfWork.Vehicles == null)
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Vehicles'  is null.");
            }

            await _unitOfWork.Vehicles.Insert(vehicle);
            await _unitOfWork.Save(HttpContext);

            return CreatedAtAction("GetVehicle", new { id = vehicle.Id }, vehicle);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Vehicles/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteVehicle(int id)
        {
            if (_unitOfWork.Vehicles == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var vehicle = await _unitOfWork.Vehicles.Get(q => q.Id == id);

            if (vehicle == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            await _unitOfWork.Vehicles.Delete(id);
            await _unitOfWork.Save(HttpContext);

            return NoContent();
        }

        private async Task<bool> VehicleExists(int id)
        {
            var vehicle = await _unitOfWork.Vehicles.Get(q => q.Id == id);
            return vehicle != null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is logical that if you get such a page, then in `Index.razor` your `Vehicles` are equal to `null`.

Try to first check that you have `Vehicles` and you receive them in the `OnInitializedAsync()` method. Then try at the end of this method to call the `StateHasChanged()` method to re-render the component. Maybe this will help

P.S. I don't have much experience with Blazor.

Comment: Great! Please, let me now if it will help you.

Comment: Hi, I managed to fix it. I realized that I did miss a OnInitializedAsync method and I havent added migration as I edit the domain file before this. Thank you so much for your help:)